# How to convert datetime format from yyyy-MM-dd to yyyy/MM/dd in C++?

Tags: c++, date, datetime, formatting

all

I am quite new to C++.

Here is my code.

```
#include <winnls.h>
#include <winnt.h>



SYSTEMTIME create_local_time;

GetDateFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_SHORTDATE, &create_local_time, NULL, m_szCreationTime.GetBuffer(128), 128);
```

I am looking at GetDateFormat function in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318086(v=vs.85).aspx.

And m_szCreationTime returns me date in string like 2013-03-09.

I would like to change this format to 2013/03/09.

So, I am having a look at DWORD dwFlags which I gave DATE_SHORTDATE.

But still, I cannot find information that I want to.

Can somebody give me a hand?

**EDIT**

Sorry for all of you, I really missed out really important partk.

m_szCreationTime is CString type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution1

You could set the 4th parameter `format` to `"yyyy/mm/dd"` rather than `NULL`, but the second parameter `dwFlags` must be set to `0`, because:

> [Flags specifying various function options that can be set if lpFormat is set to NULL.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here we need to set the `format` parameter, so we couldn't set `dwFlags` to `NULL`. You could refer to the documentation in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) more information of this API:

```
SYSTEMTIME create_local_time;

TCHAR time[128] = {0};
const TCHAR *format = _T("yyyy/MM/dd");
GetLocalTime(&create_local_time);
GetDateFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 0, &create_local_time, format, time, 128);
```

The above code snippets could get time in the desired format.

### Solution2

You could also replace the `-` to `/` after you get the string, e.g.,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

void some_func() {
    std::string s = "2013-03-09";
    std::replace( s.begin(), s.end(), '-', '/'); // replace all '-' to '/'
}
```

If the string is `CString` type, it's even simpler:

```
szCreationTime .Replace('-', '/');
```

Please refer to the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300582%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Comment: No issues. And dont be sorry I just suggested so that you dont get a downvote! :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed out the important part. m_szCreationTime is CString type.

Comment: When I change my code to GetDateFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_SHORTDATE, &create_local_time, L"yyyy/MM/dd", m_szCreationTime.GetBuffer(128), 128);. m_szCreationTime returns empty string.

Comment: @JoshuaSon, please refer to the update answer for `CString` solution.

Comment: @JoshuaSon, please take a look at the update answer, it fixed the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s = "2013-03-09";
    replace( s.begin(), s.end(), '-', '/' );
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And how this is different from `feihu` answer?

Comment: @user3414693 sorry i didn't saw that answer.i streight away wrote th code